# Online Javascript/CSS editor for IE 8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

Is there any online editor for javascript and CSS for IE8? plunkr, jsbin, jsfiddle and snippet of stackover flow are not working in IE8.

> The reason, I'm asking is to test arrows (CSS) of tooltip which is
>   very slow in IE8 when using "pseudo css after"

[image]

```
.custom-ui-tooltip > .ui-tooltip-content:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
}

.right .ui-tooltip-content:after {
  top: 2px;
  left: -18px;
  border-color: transparent #000000;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nmusmani/2mo9e3jt/1/

*P.S: It is slow in IE8 and works fine in IE12 even emulating as IE8*

Comment: Well to be honest, IE 8 has been EOL since January 2016 (this year; didn't you get invited to the party?), so the fact that none really support it any more isn't surprising (especially considering how ass it was to support). You could go oldschool and just have a `tst.html` file on your desktop you use for specifically this (or when you want actual editor tools rather than the attempt that fiddle/dabblet/codepen/etc all provide)

Comment: IE8 is client's choice/requirement so I can't do anything in it & already using this **tst.html** thing but it is hard to test different scenarios. Any thoughts on handling above CSS snippet in IE 8?

Comment: what exactly is it doing wrong?

Comment: updated my question with image of tooltip problem area. Using CSS given in question it works fine in chrome & IE12 but in IE8 it displays after a while (just like arrow pops out)

Comment: Why not edit in some browser of your choice and then just view the result page in IE8?

Comment: IE8 performance isn't something I'm overly keen on... might wanna remake this question with a more descriptive title to what your actual question is, rather than asking about online editors- might get someone to check in that actually might have a clue. Also, you *are* using a `tst.html` or equiv, yes? because if it's an online editor it might be the editor's overhead.